# Create an index that will prevent duplicate orders for customers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created an Orders table.

```
create table orders (
    Orderid int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    OrderNumber int not null
    Customerscode int NOT NULL
    Ordertype varchar(225) NOT NULL
    DiscountPrice int NOT NULL
    CHECK (DiscountPrice<=50)
    OrderPrice int NOT NULL
    Orderdate DATE 
    PaymentStatus bit
)
```

I need to add an index that will not allow a Customer to take more than one order. The order number can be doubled as each order is for a different Customer.

This is what I started:

```sql
CREATE Index idx_orders
ON Orders(OrderNumber, CustomersCode)
```

I need help. Thanks!

Comment: An `INDEX` doesn't stop duplicate values unless it's a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define UNIQUE CONSTRAINT(in the background creates unique index) or UNIQUE INDEX for your needs.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Orders   
ADD CONSTRAINT AK_Orders UNIQUE (OrderNumber, CustomersCode);
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE Index idx_orders
ON Orders(OrderNumber, CustomersCode)
```